# Local Storage error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please someone tell me what is the problem in the code which i have written.

Js

```
 $("button").click(function() {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("asd").value;
      });
        $(function() {
            var edit = document.getElementById('demo');
            $(edit).blur(function() {
                localStorage.setItem("data1", this.innerHTML)
            });
            if (localStorage.getItem("data1")) {
                edit.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("data1");
            }
        });
```

Html

```
<input type="text" id="asd">
<button>asdsad</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

But the same code is working perfectly in this:

Js

```
$(function() {
            var edit = document.getElementById('demo');
            $(edit).blur(function() {
                localStorage.setItem("data1", document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML)
            });
            if (localStorage.getItem("data1")) {
                edit.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("data1");
            }
        });
```

HTML

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="demo">Some text here</div>
```

Please some one tell me what went wrong here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details into your post so that other users are able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the `edit` variable (which contains a DOM element) into jQuery as an argument, a jQuery object is returned.  That changes the scope of `this` inside your `blur` event to a jQuery object.  jQuery doesn't have a property of `innerHTML`, so it returns `undefined`.  JavaScript DOM elements do have an `innerHTML` property of course, so that's why the second example works.

One way to fix your first example is to replace this:

```
$(edit).blur(function() {
    localStorage.setItem("data1", this.innerHTML)
});
```

With this:

```
$(edit).blur(function() {
    localStorage.setItem("data1", $(this).html());
});
```

Comment: One other issue I see is you're trying to bind to a `.blur()` event handler to a paragraph.  Paragraphs don't fire events like `blur` and `focus` when you interact with them.  The exception is when they have a  `contenteditable`attribute whose value is `true`.  

Could you please clarify your intention with the first example code?  Do you want to save the form input's value to `localStorage` and populate the paragraph with its contents when the page is reloaded?

Comment: Yes, yes it is. I want to save the text in the paragraph in `localstorage`